# Nodejs AWS S3 Generate Presigned URL work only the second time

Tags: node.js, amazon-web-services

I just need to get my url to do the upload in the front end.
But in my situation I don't know why, I can get the url but only after the second call.

```
    const AWS = require('aws-sdk')
    const s3 = new AWS.S3()

    AWS.config.update({
      accessKeyId: 'secretId',
      secretAccessKey: 'secretAccessKeyId'
    })

    return s3.getSignedUrl('putObject', {
      Bucket: 'eps-file-default',
      Key: 'picture-test.png',
      Expires: 300
    })
```

Here you can see the first response :

```
"https://s3.amazonaws.com/" // the problem is here
```

And here you can see the second response :

```
"https://eps-file-default.s3.amazonaws.com/picture-test.png?AWSAccessKeyId=mysecret&Expires=1595246561&Signature=3uEK7zrqUDUv6hGriN3TraUnoOo%3D"
```

If you have the solution thank you so much.

Comment: Look closely at the generated URL and you should also find that it is not being signed by the credentials you assume; see `X-Amz-Credential` or `AWSAccessKeyId` in the URL for the Access Key ID actually being used.  Please confirm.

Comment: I found the solution but thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the solution! I hope this can help someone, the config have the be before.

```
    const AWS = require('aws-sdk')

    AWS.config.update({
      accessKeyId: 'secret',
      secretAccessKey: 'secret2'
    })

    const s3 = new AWS.S3()

    return s3.getSignedUrl('putObject', {
      Bucket: bucketname,
      Key: filename,
      Expires: 900
    })
```